# Neo4j Unique Labelled Node

Tags: indexing, neo4j, unique

**Note:** I am working with Neo4J 2.0.0-M02.

In previous applications, who worked with earlier versions of Neo4j (mostly 1.8.x), I've used the UniqueNodeFactory with an index on for instance, a person id. This way, I was able to create a node, only when it was needed. Because of the performance difference, I did not want to use the CREATE UNIQUE statement in Cypher, but use the Core API class:

http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0-M02/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory.html

Now, in v2.0.0-M02, I don't longer use legacy indices, but I use the schema indices based on labels. My question is, are these indices compatible with the UniqueNodeFactory, and if so, what are their names that I need to pass as a parameter to the UniqueNodeFactory constructor?

I tried with passing the actual object, but the UniqueNOdeFactory is not compatible with the IndexDefinition class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not compatible, but instead 2.0 will add uniqueness constraints on label/property, enforcing such a uniqueness automatically. Perhaps M03 will contain it.

Comment: Suppose I have a label User, and I index the property userid for that label. If I understood you correctly, I should not be able to create two labelled usernodes, with the same userid then. This uniqueness should be enforced automatically, right?

Comment: Yupp, that's what is being added